# RFX_BigInt error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, informix

I have a field

```
_int64  m_initial_amount;
```

declared in the .h file and have a corresponding line

```
RFX_BigInt(pFX, _T("[initial_amount]"), m_initial_amount);
```

defined in the .cpp file

I am getting an error `C2065: 'RFX_BigInt' : undeclared identifier`

What is the error related to?
Am I missing upon some header file, includes, libraries?

Note: I am compiling the code in VC++ 6.0?

Comment: What is RFX_BigInt supposed to be?  It isn't something I've ever seen, but the `_T` is also new to me.  What do you think it is going to do?  Is it a macro or a constructor?  Where did you copy it from?  Is there a good reason to be using VC++ 6.0?  (Did you mean `IFX_BigInt` by any chance?  The 'ifx' prefix is used by Informix on occasion (though I don't recognize `IFX_BigInt` either, but things get respelled on Windows).  Informix does have a BIGINT data type that would be mapped to `__int64` on Windows (where I think double-underscore is correct, but I'm open to persuasion otherwise).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `RFX_xxxxx` are ODBC functions to transfer data from record sets loaded in memory to variables. `_T()` is a macro that creates a wide (16 bit or more per character) or normal (8 bit per character) string depending on project settings.

Comment: @MiMo: Thanks.  I thought the `_T` was likely to be related to T-strings, and hence multi-byte etc.  Knowing what RFX_Xyz() is supposed to do is a help.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `RFX_xxxxx` macro to transfer 64 bit integer - you have to get the raw data and convert it manually to a 64 bit integer.
See documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z45tz8b.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca5a16kd.aspx

Comment: Isn't that going to be a 32-bit quantity rather than a 64-bit quantity?  Did MSVC 6 support 64-bit integers at all?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you are right, it is 32 bit and not 64. MSVC 6 does support 64 bit integers, but it appears that the `RFX_xxxx` macros of the ODBC library do not